# Debug 32 bit application with gdb in 64 bit environment

Tags: debugging, gdb, 32bit-64bit

Is there any specific step required to debug 32 bit application with 64 bit gdb under 64 bit O.S.

Normally I use -m32 switch for gcc, is there something like for gdb?

Comment: What problem are you having when you try this ?

Comment: It is very strange that, the problem is gone. I use eclipse CDT, When I tried to debug, a library mismatch was thrown(I did not note). But nothing now..

Comment: It is the message when a segfault occurs:  warning: the debug information found in "/lib/ld-2.11.1.so" does not match "/lib/ld-linux.so.2" (CRC mismatch).

Comment: Does this hold for Windows and Mingw-W64 aswell? See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40680886/debugging-32-bit-applications-with-gdb-bundled-with-minggw-w64

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No: 64-bit GDB can debug either 32 or 64-bit processes.

This message `warning: the debug information found in "/lib/ld-2.11.1.so" does not match "/lib/ld-linux.so.2" (CRC mismatch)` simply means that your installed libc-debuginfo package does not match your installed libc package, and that you will not be able to do source-level debugging on `ld-linux.so.2`. Most of the time you don't want to debug anything in `ld-linux.so.2` anyway, so the message is harmless.