# How to fix hang in gdb in ld-linux.so.2 when running a 32-bit executable on a 64-bit Ubuntu (18.04) system?

Tags: c++, gdb, ubuntu-18.04

I'm trying to debug a 32-bit executable on a 64-bit Ubuntu system. It runs just fine by itself from the command line, but when I try to use gdb, it hangs in ld-linux.so.2. Also, gdb works for the 64-bit version of the executable. Does anyone have a clue as to what I should try?

I just re-imaged a machine to Ubuntu 18.04.3, and I installed the multilib versions of gcc and g++.

Thanks in advance.

```
gdb <executable>
GNU gdb ...
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-linux-gnu"
...
Reading symbols from <executable>...done.
(gdb) show archi
The target architecture is set automatically (currently i386)
(gdb) break main
Breakpoint 1 at ...
(gdb) run
Starting program...
warning: Breakpoint address adjusted from 0xf7fd9be0 to 0xfffffffff7fd9be0.
...
(7 of these)
[hangs...]
[In another terminal, ran 'kill -CONT <pid>']
Program received signal SIGCONT, Continued.
0xf7fd9be0 in ?? () from /lib/ld-linux.so.2
(gdb) cont
[hangs again...]
```

Comment: Maybe you need 32 bit gdb as well?

Comment: I thought that at first as well, but then I saw this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3931889/debug-32-bit-application-with-gdb-in-64-bit-environment

Comment: This sounds like a bug in GDB. In particular, `0xfffffffff7fd9be0` address seems totally bogus. Try running without setting any breakpoints at all.

Comment: I don't understand your edit to my post. Were you able to reproduce this issue with gdb=8.1-0ubuntu3.1?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**UPDATE:** This problem has been fixed for Ubuntu in the [`gdb`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic-updates/gdb) package version 8.1-0ubuntu3.2, so just upgrading your packages (`sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade`) should help currently.

---

**ORIGINAL ANSWER:**

[@EmployedRussian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/50617/employed-russian) suggested in [his edit to the question](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/58225562/2):

> By downgrading from gdb=8.1-0ubuntu3.1 to gdb=8.1-0ubuntu3 the debugger started working again for me.

This also worked for me on Ubuntu 18.04.3. You should issue these commands:

```sh
sudo apt install gdb=8.1-0ubuntu3  # downgrade GDB to the working version
sudo apt-mark hold gdb  # prevent upgrading (until the repository version is fixed)
```

I created a bug report for Ubuntu: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gdb/+bug/1848200
You can click `Does this bug affect you?` if you have an Ubuntu account to get it fixed sooner.

Comment: unsatisfying - but I can confirm that this solved the issue here too -  for the time beeing.

Comment: @Fookiee Did you find my answer unsatisfying? Please suggest an improvement. Or do you find the existence of the bug unsatisfying? As you can see using the Launchpad link, the fix is currently available in the `bionic-proposed` repository and will be likely available in the default repository soon.

Comment: oh, sorry, that was indeed unclear. I meant, downgrading a packet is in general an unsatisfying workaround. But a working system is better than one which fails. I saw, that the Bug is already in state fix-verfied.

I'm really happy, that you shared the answer, so I was able to debug and fix my stuff already on Monday

Answer (score 2):

Probably this gdb bug:
https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=23210

Try upgrading to the current GDB version (8.3.1). If Ubuntu doesn't offer a package for that, you can try compiling it yourself.

Answer (score 2):

This is now fixed in 8.1-0ubuntu3.2 in bionic-updates: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gdb/8.1-0ubuntu3.2

Comment: Hello dann!  Could you please provide a relevant link in your answer with a quote referring to the cancelled feature?

Comment: @isakbob OK, added a link