# GDB - Breakpoint address adjusted warning

Tags: gcc, assembly, gdb

I'm learning assembly (GAS) language and using gdb to debug my programs (OS Ubuntu 18.04 x64).

I used this command to create x86 executable file:

```
gcc -g -m32 -nostdlib -o "prog" "prog.s"
```

Next I run `gdb -q prog`, set breakpoint with `break line-number` and `run`. And all was working till gcc-update (I think so).
Now with updated gcc (7.4.0) after running `gdb -q prog` I get this warning and program hangs:

```
Starting program: /home/test/asm/prog 
warning: Breakpoint address adjusted from 0xf7fe5db0 to 0xfffffffff7fe5db0.
^C
Program received signal SIGINT, Interrupt.
0xf7fe5db0 in _dl_debug_state () from /lib/ld-linux.so.2
(gdb) quit
A debugging session is active.

    Inferior 1 [process 9600] will be killed.

Quit anyway? (y or n) y
```

Can someone advice please? What happened and why can't I use gcc anymore to create x86 executables?

Now, to use gdb I create x86 executable using these lines:

```
as --32 --gstabs "prog.s" -o "prog.o"
ld -m elf_i386 "prog.o" -o "prog"
```

Next I use `gdb -q prog` and everything works fine: I set breakpoints, run program and it stops at breakpoints without warnings and hanging.

I tried this at several assembly examples, even the simpliest one as this:

```
.section .text
.globl _start
_start:
movl $0, %ebx
movl $1, %eax
int $0x80
```

And even here I get `breakpoint adjusted warning` and program hangs in gdb...

I did not try previous version of gcc, because I don't know how to install it.

Tried `sudo apt-get install gcc=4:7.3.0-3ubuntu2`, but `gcc --version` shows latest - 4.7.4.

I think it is because gcc is a symbolic link at `/usr/bin/gcc` which points to `/usr/bin/gcc-7` which has version 7.4.0.

```
dpkg -l | grep gcc

ii  gcc                                        4:7.3.0-3ubuntu2                             amd64        GNU C compiler
ii  gcc-7                                      7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1                       amd64        GNU C compiler
ii  gcc-7-base:amd64                           7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1                       amd64        GCC, the GNU Compiler Collection (base package)
ii  gcc-7-multilib                             7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1                       amd64        GNU C compiler (multilib support)
ii  gcc-8-base:amd64                           8.3.0-6ubuntu1~18.04.1                       amd64        GCC, the GNU Compiler Collection (base package)
ii  lib32gcc-7-dev                             7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1                       amd64        GCC support library (32 bit development files)
ii  lib32gcc1                                  1:8.3.0-6ubuntu1~18.04.1                     amd64        GCC support library (32 bit Version)
ii  libgcc-7-dev:amd64                         7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1                       amd64        GCC support library (development files)
ii  libgcc1:amd64                              1:8.3.0-6ubuntu1~18.04.1                     amd64        GCC support library
ii  libx32gcc-7-dev                            7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1                       amd64        GCC support library (x32 development files)
ii  libx32gcc1                                 1:8.3.0-6ubuntu1~18.04.1                     amd64        GCC support library (x32)
```

And command `sudo apt-get install gcc-7=7.3.0-16ubuntu3` failed with errors:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gcc-7 : Depends: cpp-7 (= 7.3.0-16ubuntu3) but 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1 is to be installed
         Depends: gcc-7-base (= 7.3.0-16ubuntu3) but 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1 is to be installed
         Depends: libgcc-7-dev (= 7.3.0-16ubuntu3) but 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Please, give me advice, why can't I debug executable generated from gcc?
I've used `objdump -D` on executables from **ld** and **gcc**. They are different, but I don't know how it can help me.

Comment: This is very likely a dup of https://stackoverflow.com/q/58225562. In particular, your GDB probably has this bug: https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=23210