# Why does 64-bit gdb never reach breakpoint in ARM 32 code?

Tags: debugging, assembly, arm, gdb

I am running Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS and `lscpu` answers the following:

```
Architecture:                    aarch64
CPU op-mode(s):                  32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:                      Little Endian
CPU(s):                          4
On-line CPU(s) list:             0-3
Thread(s) per core:              1
Core(s) per socket:              4
Socket(s):                       1
NUMA node(s):                    1
Vendor ID:                       ARM
Model:                           0
Model name:                      Cortex-A57
Stepping:                        r1p0
BogoMIPS:                        125.00
NUMA node0 CPU(s):               0-3
Vulnerability Itlb multihit:     Not affected
Vulnerability L1tf:              Not affected
Vulnerability Mds:               Not affected
Vulnerability Meltdown:          Not affected
Vulnerability Spec store bypass: Vulnerable
Vulnerability Spectre v1:        Mitigation; __user pointer sanitization
Vulnerability Spectre v2:        Vulnerable
Vulnerability Srbds:             Not affected
Vulnerability Tsx async abort:   Not affected
Flags:                           fp asimd evtstrm aes pmull sha1 sha2 crc32 cpuid
```

I have created a trivial assembly language program as follows:

```
        .text
        .global _start
_start:
        MOV     R0, #1
        LDR     R1, =hello
        LDR     R2, =hello_size
        MOV     R7, #4
        SWI     0
        MOV     R7, #1
        SWI     0

        .data
hello:  .asciz  "Happy Friday\n"
        .equ    hello_size, (.-hello)
```

I compile it with the following:

```
arm-linux-gnueabihf-as -ggdb hello.s -o out.o
arm-linux-gnueabihf-ld out.o -o out -lc -dynamic-linker=/usr/arm-linux-gnueabihf/lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3
```

When I run it directly from the command line it prints the expected output ("Happy Friday\n"). I can disassemble the code as follows:

```
$ objdump -d out

out:     file format elf32-littlearm


Disassembly of section .text:

0001016c <_start>:
   1016c:   e3a00001    mov r0, #1
   10170:   e59f1010    ldr r1, [pc, #16]   ; 10188 <_start+0x1c>
   10174:   e59f2010    ldr r2, [pc, #16]   ; 1018c <_start+0x20>
   10178:   e3a07004    mov r7, #4
   1017c:   ef000000    svc 0x00000000
   10180:   e3a07001    mov r7, #1
   10184:   ef000000    svc 0x00000000
   10188:   0002100c    .word   0x0002100c
   1018c:   0000000e    .word   0x0000000e
```

I would like to run it in a debugger (as part of a class I'm teaching on ARM assembly language). Here is what I do:

```
$ gdb out
GNU gdb (Ubuntu 9.2-0ubuntu1~20.04) 9.2
...
Reading symbols from out...
(gdb) b _start
Breakpoint 1 at 0x1016c: file hello.s, line 4.
(gdb) run
Starting program: /home/fostja/code/280/samples/out
```

At this point the program hangs. Interrupting the program gives the following:

```
^C
Program received signal SIGINT, Interrupt.
0x0000aaaadca1a284 in ?? ()
(gdb) bt
#0  0x0000aaaadca1a284 in ?? ()
#1  0x000000000000afc7 in ?? ()
Backtrace stopped: previous frame identical to this frame (corrupt stack?)
(gdb)
```

I'm at a loss as to why it is hanging and never gets to the first breakpoint. At first I thought that it had something to do with Qemu emulating the instruction that should trigger the breakpoint in the debugger (I tried this first on Proxmox, so much of the discussion focuses there) but now it appears to be something to do with 32-bit and 64-bit.

A "fixed" bug in `gdb` seems quite similar. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58225562/how-to-fix-hang-in-gdb-in-ld-linux-so-2-when-running-a-32-bit-executable-on-a-64) and [this](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gdb/+bug/1848200).

Comment: Actually, I've now answered, but realised maybe my assumption is wrong. Do you run `gdb` inside `qemu`?

Comment: If it is inside, then disregard my answer, and try adding `-semihosting-config enable=off` parameter when you start `qemu`.

Comment: Yes, I'm doing everything from the guest: vim, as, gdb. I'm not trying to do remote debugging. Other than being very slow, this should be just a plain vanilla Ubuntu 20.04 server. I'll try the suggested qemu options.

Comment: And, no, disabling semihosting does not solve the problem.

Comment: Oh, this is interesting. And nothing in qemu monitor logs? Are all of the commands in your question run inside qemu? Asking because it's a bit odd to see `arm-linux-gnueabihf-` unless one is crosscompiling.

Comment: As to logs, I don't see anything in the Proxmox web system. As to the commands, yes, I'm doing everything from the guest. As to the crosscompiler, I'm not sure why that is being used. Might it be because I'm trying to assemble 32-bit code on a 64-bit system? (I'm new at a lot of this!)

Maybe my question should be, "How can I assemble, run, and debug code that matches the textbook I'm using to teach the class on a 64-bit system (I can't find Ubuntu 20.04 for 32-bit ARM)." The textbook is Kris Schindler's Introduction to Microprocessor Based Systems Using the ARM Processor. Thanks.

Comment: Does gdb otherwise work? Can you single step, dump memory etc.? When you show registers in gdb ("i regi"), does it show 32 or 64-bit arm registers?

Comment: As shown in the original question, I can start `gdb`, set breakpoints, start/run, interrupt code, and `bt` reports a corrupt stack. The command `i regi` shows registers x0 to x30, along with sp, pc, and cpsr. So this looks like 64 bit instead of the r0-r15 that I expect from the 32-bit environment. [By the way, Stack Overflow says that I should avoid extended discussions in comments. I appreciate your help but don't want to abuse the system!]

Comment: I've tried writing, assembling, running, and debugging a 64-bit program (changing register names from r1 to w1, and it works fine. So the problem is one of debugging a 32-bit program. That should at least help focus the research!

Comment: I've reproduced the problem on EC2 from AWS with native ARM hardware, so the problem is unrelated to Proxmox and qemu. I suspect that it is a regression of https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gdb/+bug/1848200.

Comment: Reported to `gdb` as https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gdb/+bug/1901966.

Comment: James: If you have the time/inclination it would be worth trying to repro with a head-of-upstream-gdb and reporting the bug to gdb directly rather than against ubuntu's gdb package.

Answer (score 2):

**This would answer it, if `gdb` was run *outside* of `qemu`, on host. This is not the case of this question.**

---

You need to use **gdbserver** in qemu, and then connect to it.

In qemu:

```
(qemu) gdbserver
gdbserver
Waiting for gdb connection on device 'tcp::1234'
```

In gdb, you then have to connect to it (might need to adjust to be in line with output from qemu):

```
(gdb) target remote localhost:1234
Remote debugging using localhost:1234
```

Source: https://linux.postach.io/post/debugging-linux-kernel-using-virtual-machine-qemu-monitor-and-gdb (or pretty much any other website that mentions gdbserver and qemu)

Comment: I want gdb to execute inside the guest machine, so this doesn't help at all.