# GDB-Run Executable Doesn't Work (VS Code)

Tags: gcc, visual-studio-code, gdb, mingw

I am using VS Code for a C++ Project. I am also using CMake Tools to manage the CMake side of things and my compiler toolchains.

I have two separate compiler kits - i686-w64-mingw32 and x86_64-w64-mingw32 (gcc version 10.1.0).

I have set the gdb.exe path in my launch.json to the path of the 64-bit gdb debugger. This works correctly and I can run and debug with breakpoints as expected.

However, when running the 32-bit executable with the 64-bit debugger, I get no output to my console whatsoever, and the breakpoint is not hit.

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't mix platforms. Debug the 32-bit executable with the 32-bit debugger.

Comment: The 64-bit GDB is perfectly capable of debugging 32-bit executables. See here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3931889/debug-32-bit-application-with-gdb-in-64-bit-environment. Unfortunately my current setting using CMake Tools makes it a bit of a mission to switch debuggers like that and I'd like to make everything as automated as possible.

Comment: Have you tried doing this via command line? Do you get an error?
If I try to debug a 32-bit process with 64-bit gdb I do see some warnings that match this: https://virtuallyfun.com/wordpress/2015/10/04/32bit-64bit-gdb-collision/

Comment: I have not yet, but I have re-asked this question with a detailed output log here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62404382/gdb-unknown-target-exception-when-debugging-32-bit-target-with-64-bit-environme.
Side note - are you Brecht Sanders i.e. from Winlibs? I happen to be using your build of MinGW-w64! Haha, thanks very much. So if it isn't working for you then we are in exactly the same boat it seems? Why does that other link mention that it is possible? @brecht-sanders

Comment: @gasko Yes, I'm the guy from http://winlibs.com where separating 32-bit and 64-bit toolchains completely is part of the philosophy in order to avoid any possible problems when the 2 get mixed up (as I noticed on stackoverflow happens a lot).

Comment: Haha. I just got a reply on my other question stating that it is supported on Linux but not on Windows just yet, but will be for GDB version 10. Thanks for the help!

Comment: That's good news. As soon as GDB 10 is released I start working on a new http://winlibs.com build ;-)