# Debugging x32 application using x64 gdb

Tags: c, gdb

I've built a 32-bit application on C using gcc (tdm-64-1) on my x64 machine. I need to have a debugger, which is gdb. But the problem is it doesn't work with x32. Is there any way to make it work?
That's the gdb output when I try to debug it:

```
Reading symbols from test.exe...
(gdb) break 5
Breakpoint 1 at 0x401533: file d:\1\a\test.c, line 10.
(gdb) start
Temporary breakpoint 2 at 0x40156b: file d:\1\a\test.c, line 21.
Starting program: D:\1\a\test.exe
warning: `C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll': Shared library architecture i386:x86-64 is not compatible with target architecture i386.
warning: `C:\WINDOWS\System32\wow64.dll': Shared library architecture i386:x86-64 is not compatible with target architecture i386.
warning: `C:\WINDOWS\System32\wow64win.dll': Shared library architecture i386:x86-64 is not compatible with target architecture i386.
warning: `C:\WINDOWS\System32\wow64cpu.dll': Shared library architecture i386:x86-64 is not compatible with target architecture i386.
[New Thread 4784.0x31c4]
gdb: unknown target exception 0x4000001f at 0x40156b

Thread 1 received signal ?, Unknown signal.
0x0009df38 in ?? ()
```

Comment: According to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62404382/gdb-unknown-target-exception-when-debugging-32-bit-target-with-64-bit-environme it is (will get?) fixed in GDB 10. Try `git clone --branch gdb-10-branch git://sourceware.org/git/binutils-gdb.git` and see if the gdb you've build with that branch is useful in your case.

Comment: [README-gdb-tdm64](https://github.com/jmeubank/tdm-distrib/blob/master/tdm64/gdb/README-gdb-tdm64.md) suggests that you need to use "gdb32" to debug 32-bit applications.

Comment: It's kinda odd that I have to download an entirely different app to debug x32 if I can do -m32 in gcc...